# While reading an oracle view from php :ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: php, oracle, select, view, decimal

this query it works!

```
SELECT largdisp  FROM vcantieri WHERE SEQ_EVENTO=97161
```

(value of largdisp is 600 and it works for any value 500,600,700...1000 or null)

this query gives an ERROR! ORA-06502

```
SELECT largdisp  FROM vcantieri WHERE SEQ_EVENTO=97195
```

(value of largdisp 650 and not works for any value 750,850,950....)

largdisp is a decimal field in original table, converted in varchar2 in view

IN TOAD this query it works always!!!

Comment: What is the data type of SEQ_EVENTO in the view (and in the underlying table)?

Comment: number! while largdisp in original table is a decimal ...value stored in table are 6.5, 7.5, 8.5 .... converted in varchar2 without (.) in view

Comment: Can you post the table and view definitions?

Comment: Please read and heed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: is `vcantieri` a table?

Comment: vcantieri is a view

Comment: You need to update the question with the view details. Something in the view is causing a varchar2 column to be converted to a number (e.g. because you're comparing the column to a number) but there's something in the column that isn't numeric data which prevents that conversion from taking place

Comment: largdisp is VARCHAR2 (6 Byte)

Comment: forcing conversion the result does not change SELECT  CAST(LARGDISP AS VARCHAR2(6)) AS larg FROM vcantieri WHERE SEQ_EVENTO=97195    ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error